# Wrap text after particular symbol with jQuery

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do, is wrap text into div inside ll tag. It wouldn't be a problem, but I need to wrap text that appears particularly after "-" (minus) including "minus" itself.

This is my html:

```
<ul>
    <li>Some list text - Additional text</li>
</ul>
```

As I result I'm trying to achieve this:

```
<ul>
     <li>Some list text <span class="after">- Additional text<span></li>
</ul>
```

Will anyone will be able to help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are these "-" signs meant to be bullets, and is the "additional text" meant to describe or eleborate upon "some list text"?

Comment: If you like I modify my answer to include some jQuery code to change the ul to a dl, the li to a dt, wrap all the "-" delimited text in dd elements, but I strongly urge you to consider what you are trying to display here and make sure it comes across semantically.  For most of your users will see what looks like a descriptive list, but others using assistive devices will have a hard time trying to figure out what you are trying to convey here.  Look at your page with a screen reader to see what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```
$('li').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/-.*$/, '<span class="after">$&</span>'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to create some sort of descriptive list instead of a simple unordered list.  If you need to keep all the text within a single element I'm sure someone will post a decent solution, but why not use a `dl` instead of a `ul` like so:

```
 <dl>
      <dt>Some list text</dt>
      <dd>- additional text</dd>
 <dl>
```

This should achieve the same effect as trying to cause the text after a "-" sign to appear on a new line, and you can modify the padding and margin on the `<dt>` and `<dl>` elements so that they line up if that is the look you are going for.  If you are creating a descriptive list with list items (`<dt>`) with further sub list items describing them (`<dd>`) its better to imply that in the semantics for accessibility than to approximate the same thing using another method.

**EDIT:** Before anyone says anything I am aware that the question asked for a solution using `jQuery`, and that this solution doesn't use jQuery.  But if the intent here is to approximate a descriptive list it's better to code that semantically in the HTML than use jQuery magic.

Answer (score 1):

This will insert a linebreak before every - in a list item.

```
$(function(){
  $("li").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(\-\, "<br />-"));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're on track. Make the `span` a block-level element like so:

```
<span class='after' style='display: block;'>...</span>
```

And see if that does it.

Oh, and then move that inline style into your stylesheet :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this below should do it, note this was dry-coded here in my browser, so testing is required.

```
$('ul li').each(function() {
    var parts = $(this).html().split('-', 1);

    $(this).html(parts[0]);
    if (parts.length == 2) {
        $(this).append(" - " + parts[1]);
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($("li:contains('-')"),function(i,n){
  n.innerHTML = n.innerHTML.replace('-','<span class="after">-')+"</span>"
});
```

Comment: "One-liner" is a misnomer when you're removing all spaces and cramming everything together into an unreadable mess ;)  I'm not sure that's even correct since it only wraps the `-` and not the text following it.

Comment: Should work. He's sticking the <span> before the hyphen, and then appending a </span> after the rest of the content.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, you are right, I shouldn't have compressed it down into a single line (to many years coding Perl ;).  It does work, though.