# Wrap text following a particular element with <p>

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got some HTML like this:

```
<div class="text">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/><a href="http://www.example.com" class="ht">the link</a>
    this element doesn't look right, the text displays next to the link
</div>
<div class="text">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/><a href="http://www.example.com" class="ht">the link</a> 
    <p>this is a proper kind of element, i want them wrapped in paragraphs or at least looking like they've been wrapped in paragraphs</p>
</div>
```

and I was wondering if it would be possible to make the text from the first example `<div>` display below the link, like wrapping a `<p></p>` around the text, with jQuery. It's not possible to change the HTML because it's a user-generated comments kind of project, and I can't exactly force the user to put `<p></p>` around their text. Most of them do, but some of them don't so I need to find a solution to make them all display the same.

I've done some research and I found this answer: [Selecting text only following certain elements using javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894691/selecting-text-only-following-certain-elements-using-javascript-jquery) 
but it doesn't really answer my question as that's based on a particular fixed structure of text and what I have as text can really be anything the user inputs and I need it to display below the image and the link, which display on the same line. This solution: [Wrap text after particular symbol with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701532/wrap-text-after-particular-symbol-with-jquery) also doesn't work for me because there is no set HTML that I can use to identify the unwrapped text. This one: [Find text in element that is NOT wrapped in html tags and wrap it with <p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506770/find-text-in-element-that-is-not-wrapped-in-html-tags-and-wrap-it-with-p) also doesn't do what I need because sometimes we have people using `<b></b>` and `<i></i>`

Other things I've tried:

- Making the image and link have `display:block;` and `float:left;` which
  doesn't work because the text still displays on the same line as the
  image and link
- Making the image and link have `display:block;` without the float -
  doesn't work because the image and link don't display on the same
  line anymore
- Using `$("a.ht").next()` to select, which just doesn't work

So if anyone could help me out with this I'd be really grateful, thank you!

EDIT: Here's an example of what I want:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused; you say you don't want the image and text on the same line, yet say that `display: block` doesn't work because it puts things on different lines. That makes no sense. It would be helpful if you showed the layout you want to have

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm sorry for your confusion, I've added an image to explain my aim

Comment: Thanks for the update. @madalin's answer seems to fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```js
$('.text').each(function() {
  var el = $(this).clone().find('img,.ht');//get the image and the title 
  var text = el.remove().end().html();//remove the elements, get the remaining html
  $(this).html(el).append('<p>' + text + '</p>');//add the p with the remaining html

});
```

```css
p {color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><a href="http://www.example.com" class="ht">the link</a>
  this element doesn't look right, the text displays next to the link
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /><a href="http://www.example.com" class="ht">the link</a>
  this element doesn't look right, the <b>text displays next</b> to the <i>link</i>
</div>
```

Comment: This works well when the text doesn't have any other html tags inside it, but when there's <b></b> and <i></i> and <a href=""></a> it breaks because the things are appended in the wrong order... https://jsfiddle.net/do1k06c8/2/

Comment: Works nicely now, thank you. :) I just had to add a separate class to the first link in the div with .first() and use that added class instead of .ht, but the main technique works very well.